# Copy asset with location found via shell function

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an asset which needs to be copied to the docker image, but whose location I do not know beforehand: I need to run a shell command to find it:

```
where-is-my-asset
```

How can this be combined with the `COPY` command in a Dockerfile? Usually I do:

```
COPY app.json /usr/src/app
```

But now I need to do:

```
COPY `where-is-my-asset` /usr/src/app
```

Answer (score 4):

[`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) will let you define a dynamic argument to the build but I don't believe you can run a command in the `Dockerfile` to populate the argument.

You could source it beforehand. With a Dockerfile like...

```
FROM busybox
ARG assetfile
COPY $assetfile /somehwere
```

Then run

```
docker build --build-arg assetfile="$(where-is-my-asset)" .
```

Which is not much different to just doing it in the shell.

```
cp "$(where-is-my-asset)" .
docker build .
```

Comment: Yep, I was getting to the same conclusion myself: just prepare the directory before calling `docker build`